# Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UICollectionView'

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

Trying to initialize a collection view class and getting the following error:

> Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UICollectionView'

data is being passed from another ViewController and I wish to draw out the frame from within the ViewController when a user searches.

```
class searchLocationsCollectionViewManager: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
    didSet {
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
}

// Data handler
var data: [[String:Any]]? {
    didSet {
        print(data!)
        //collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

init(collectionView: UICollectionView, frame: CGRect) {
    self.collectionView = collectionView
    super.init()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}



func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

// This is the current method for returning the cell.
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {




    return UICollectionViewCell()

}
```

Any ideas on why the above is happening?

Comment: What is the purpose of an  `UICollectionView` property in an `UICollectionView ` subclass? Consider that `didSet` is not called when the initial value is assigned. And in case you mean `UICollectionViewController` there is already an `UICollectionView` property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call designated initializer [`init(frame:collectionViewLayout:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618053-init) of `UICollectionView`.

```
init(collectionView: UICollectionView, frame: CGRect) {        
    self.collectionView = collectionView
    //Setup collectionView layout here and pass with init 
    let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
    super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
}
```

Comment: My class is extending from UICollectionView and it doesn't have collectionView property saying: Value of type 'MyCollectionView' has no member 'collectionView'

Comment: Why this is only for UICollectionViewController?

Comment: Why UICollectionView doesn't have collectionView

Comment: @Daniella because `UICollectionView` don't have collectionView property you need to create object of your `MyCollectionView` which extends `UICollectionView`.